# Yii recommendation for custom interface

Tags: php, yii

I just want to follow conventions and i need to know where do i place a custom interface i want classes to ipmplement.

I know it's a recommendation only but would be good to know what you think?

Thanks,
Danny

Comment: Don't know it would be a interface for what?

Comment: @FabioCosta just a generic interface for language classes to inherit in order to keep a unified function format...

Comment: But... do you need localisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has too many answers. I suggest you to try and try different ways to use Yii. For example, I like to develop ONLY in modules. Why? Is the simplest way to re-use my code. But this is my way to code. Is my "need".

What do your application need? There are some way to develop reusable actions. So, what is the right one? Depends on your needs.

Sometimes people ask "is bettere MySQL or SQLite?". And the asnwer can be "maybe just a json or a text file".

Are you alone or inside a team? Ask the team.

Or, ... just try, and be confident with you and with different approach.

Comment: Nice answer....my need was multiple languages that had to fit 1 format... so what i did was create an extension with an interface and a per language file that implement that.

Comment: ? I do not understand what do you mean.